# Is it possible to add headers for CORS at the calling side server?

Tags: java, servlets, gwt, cors

I have a GWT appilcation in which the client makes a request to another domain. 
I wrote the request using RequestBuilder in GWT.

On executing the code, I get an error in my browser :

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

So I google and I found that the domain to which I am making the request should add this header in the response that it sends. Now I dont't have control over the other domain's server, so I can't do any modification there.

My question is, can I intercept the response and the  Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to the response that is being sent by the other domain's server at my server, before I send it to my client?
I tried using Filters but the Filter doesn't get called for responses coming from another domain.

Is this possible to do, am I missing something or is it just not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vivek's answer that cross domain requests aren't allowed by the browser is true, except for the [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) mechanism, whereby newer browsers that support it can try in a cross origin way to servers that also support it.

However, unless that remote server support it itself, there is nothing you can do. If I server my app from A, and want to connect to B, only B can authorize that. If A were allowed to permit my app to connect to B via some filter or servlet, then I could write an app that makes calls to gmail or facebook or twitter and read/write your settings and personal data at those other urls.

So instead, it is the cross origin server that you are contacting that must approve the connection with the header you mentioned. In lieu of that, you can still use your own server as a proxy for the cross origin server.

Comment: If I can have my server as a proxy and try to authorise the CORS header, so that my browser does send the request to the other domain server, would the other domain server send out the data I am requesting for? Based on what you said, I think it's not possible. Then I don't see why we have to have our own server as a proxy. Can you explain that a bit?

Comment: If you use your server as a proxy, CORS is not needed. For CORS to work, the JS app must request the remote server to allow CORS, and the remote server must approve it - your server is not involved in that conversation (and can't be, otherwise this would be a great way to attack other sites). Those are essentially the two options: *either* the remote server can handle CORS *or* you use your own server as a proxy.

Comment: ok I understand better now. I was under the assumption that it is my server that would be sending the request to the other domain server and not the JS app. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Cross-domain requests are forbidden by web browsers as per the same origin security policy. These restrictions are limited to browser based applications and hence you can definitely use your own server application as a filter between the GWT based client side application and the external server.